# Getting values of elements passed in data attribute through JQuery

Tags: jquery

I have some field names populated in the data element.  I'm trying to form a query string with the field names and their corresponding values in the form for using in jquery ajax.  The following code however, does not work for me.

```
$(".linkedfill").change(function(){
  var params = $(this).data("select-params").split(",");
  $.each(params, function(index,value){
     pname = value.slice(value.IndexOf("["), value.IndexOf("]"));
     pval = $(this).parents().find("[name='"+value+"']").val();
     addparams = addparams + "&" + pname + "=" + pval;
  });
});
```

The field name will be like `header['fldname']` and the field is available somewhere in the same form.  The data-select-params will be like `data-select-params="header['fld1'],header['fld2']"`.

**Update :** My html for fields would look like this:

```
<input name='header[fld1]' />
<input name='header[fld2]' />
<select class='linkedfill' name='pselect' data-select-params="header[fld1],header[fld2]">
  <option value="opt1">Option 1</option>
  <option value="opt2">Option 2</option>
</select>
```

What am trying to do with jquery is get the values of `header[fld1]` & `header[fld2]` and form a query string out of the data.

Can anyone help me fix this?  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
var data="header['fld1'],header['fld2']";
var params = data.split(",");
var addparams='';
$.each(params, function(index,value){
     console.log(value.indexOf("['")+','+value.indexOf("']")+','+value);
     pname = value.substring(value.indexOf("['")+2, value.indexOf("']"));
     pval = $('form').find("header["+pname+"]").val();
     addparams = addparams + "&" + pname + "=" + pval;
     console.log(addparams);
});
```

**Fiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/Ju297/1/

I don't know what you want but you can make it simple like,

```
var data="fld1,fld2";
var params = data.split(",");
var addparams='';
$.each(params, function(index,value){
     pval = $('form').find("header["+value+"]").val();
     addparams = addparams + "&" + value + "=" + pval;
     console.log(addparams);
});
```

Comment: Thanks.  I could get the first part of my issue solved.  pname worked with `pname = value.slice(value.indexOf("[")+1, value.indexOf("]"));` However, the pval does not fetch any value (undefined).  Updated my question with further details. I think the issue is with the `$(this)` part as the context changing from the base object (`.linkedfill`) to `params`?  I tried `$('form').find..` but that doesn't work either.

Comment: @Ravi test the above I have made changes.

Comment: Hi. Thanks. I cannot hardcode 'header' because it can be anything.  I have found the issue was with the object context as I suspected.  I added `var oelem=$(this); // linkedfill` at the top and edited pval line as `pval = oelem.parents().find("[name='"+value+"']").val();` which worked.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you make an array of parameters , like :

```
//if you need you can iterate the header[h1]..header[hn] push inside the function below
$('.linkedfill').data('select-params', ["header[h1]","header[h2]",...,"header[hn]"]);
```

and then access it with

```
$.each($('.linkedfill').data() , function() {
 console.log($('.linkedfill').data());
// ..do your stuff..
})
```

here is it a fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/DgbRn/

Comment: Think my detailing was not clear.  Updated the question with more details.  Thanks for your effort though.